# Bash - redirect to file (bug)?

Tags: bash, grep

I am baffled by this example:

```
[ziga@brane ~]$ touch test.txt
[ziga@brane ~]$ echo "TEST" > test.txt
[ziga@brane ~]$ cat test.txt
TEST
[ziga@brane ~]$ cat test.txt | grep "TEST"
TEST
[ziga@brane ~]$ cat test.txt | grep "TEST" > test.txt
[ziga@brane ~]$ cat test.txt
[ziga@brane ~]$
```

Why does `cat test.txt | grep "TEST" > test.txt` delete contents of a file `test.txt`? I thought that `>` rewrites and `>>` appends! What am I missing?

Comment: Also covered in [Warning regarding ‘>’](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/80216).

Answer (score 1):

because redirection happens first `>test.txt` so it truncate the file at very first, next `cat test.txt` read nothing and nothing pass to `| grep "TEST"` and so then nothing matches and finally nothing writes to opened file `test.txt`